# Find the supremum and the infimum of $A=\{x \in \Bbb R \mid 2x^2 < x^3 + x\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Find the supremum and the infimum of $A=\{x \in \Bbb R \mid 2x^2 < x^3 + x\}$.

**Attempt:**
\begin{align*}
A &= \{x \in \Bbb R \mid 2x^2 < x^3+x \}
\\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x(x^2-2x+1) > 0\}
\\
&= \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x(x-1)^2 > 0 \} \\
&= (0,1) \cup (1, \infty).
\end{align*}

Clearly, $\sup(A)$ doesn't exist since $A$ doesn't have an upper bound.

Now, for all $x \in A, x > 0$ and so, $0$ is a lower bound of $A$. Let $m$ be a lower bound of $A$. Want to show that $m\le 0$. Suppose that $m>0$ with $m \ne 1$. Let $r$ be a rational number with $0 < r < m$. Then, $r \in A$ and $m>r$,  contradiction, since $m$ is a lower bound of $A$. Therefore, $m \le 0$ and so, $\inf(A)=0$.

Am I true?

Comment: Yes, you are true, fine considerations

Comment: @Fred Great, thanks Sir.

Comment: How do you know that $r\not =1$? I think you should show that $m<1$ before concluding that.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcut approach.

As your work indicates, the inequality is satisfied if and only if $(x)(x-1)^2 > 0,$ and that this inequality will never be satisfied for either $x=1$ or $x \leq 0.$

All that remains is to show (or **simply state**) that for **any** $x> 0$ such that $x \neq 1$, each of the pertinent factors $x$ and $(x-1)^2$ must be strictly positive.